# Distance between points in interval is at most length of interval

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

If $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$, then prove that $|b - c| \leq |a - d|$.

This is intuitively obvious, but I have been banging my head against the wall for some time now writing down applications of the (regular and reverse) triangle inequality to no avail.

Comment: Since you know the order, you can just try to prove $c-b\leq d-a$.  No need to use triangle inequality here, just use transitivity of $\leq$ and the fact that it respects addition and subtraction.

Comment: I'm not sure that a triangle inequality is valuable here; you have that $|a-b| + |b-c| + |c-d| = |a - d|$, from which the desired inequality follows since $|a-b|$, $|c-d|$ are both $\geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this answer won't be too overkill.

Since we are simply thinking of distance between the two intervals, we may drag the whole expression along the positive end of the number line, until $0 \leq a$. Now, with all terms being non-negative.

Therefore, we can remove the absolute values, giving us $c-b \leq d-a$.

Rearranging, we need to prove $a+c\leq b+d$.

This is true, since $c \leq d$ and $a\leq b$, which are both given. Adding these two inequalities results in $a+c \leq b+d$.

Comment: Oops, thank you.